# Заголовочный файл conio.h

Tags: c

Что за заголовочный файл такой <conio.h>, и для чего он нужен? В K&R такой не описывают. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `<conio.h>` не нужен.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`<conio.h>`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) содержит описание нестандартной библиотеки для работы с консолью (`clrscr`, `kbhit` и тому подобное). Поставляется, ЕМНИП, со старыми Борландовскими компиляторами. Не пользуйтесь ей, если хотите, чтобы ваш код компилировался на более современных компиляторах.

---

Заметьте, что непосредственная работа с консолью противоречит философии юниксовских утилит, которые должны одинаково хорошо работать как с входными данными, полученными от пользователя, так и с выводом других программ. Поэтому правильная юниксовская утилита должна читать ввод из stdin и выводить его в stdout/stderr, позволяя эффективно использовать перенаправление потоков ввода-вывода.

Comment: Ну, и в комплекте с майкрософтовским компилятором такой файл есть

Comment: Легко сказать "не пользуйтесь".  А предложите аналог getch() из стандартных библиотек (описанных в K&R).

Comment: @Egor: `getch` тоже не нужен, разумеется. Если вы, конечно, не пишете игру или что-то ещё системно-зависимое (но тогда вам нужна гораздо болеетесная интеграция с системой).

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff: я наверное слишком категоричен, но интерактивность не так уж часто нужна в реальных проектах. А если уж нужна, то скорее не в текстовом варианте, а в графическом. Единственное исключение, приходящее в голову — ввод пароля без отображения.

Comment: @VladD, даже больше - весь conio.h в реальных задачах не нужен :) Считывание пароля из консоли там, где есть conio.h...

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff а чем Вас getchar() не устраивает?

Comment: @alexlz - getch() меня полностью устраивает.  Меня не устраивает заявление о якобы ненужности conio.h  :-)

Comment: А в чём его нужность? Повторяю: для реальных задач, а не для игрушечных упражнений под DOS.

Comment: @VladD - с каких это пор у нас игры стали системно-зависимыми?  Ну-ка скажите, от какой такой системы зависит тетрис на консоли?  Можно только сказать, что Юникс сам себе кое-что отгрыз, ограничив ввод только из файлов.  
Простейшая программа ввода пароля со звёздочками не может быть сделана портируемой :-(  Приходится отдельно писать линуксовую часть и отдельно виндовую.

Comment: Само собой, системно-зависимые части нужно писать отдельно. Но они составляют крохотную часть всего кода. Взять, к примеру, древний TurboVision и посмотреть, сколько там под ифдефами для dos16, dos32, windows и linux? Да копейки по сравнению с остальным. А что касается DOS, так в те времена, когда это было актуально, программисты забывали про conio.h как только узнавали про int16h, int9h и работу с видеопамятью.

Comment: @klopp - отвечу на реплику "для реальных задач, а не для игрушек".  Без обид, но вы напоминаете недалёких деятелей прошлого, утверждавших разную хрень: что компьютер исключительно для бизнес-задач (расчётов и отображения числовых данных), и никому в голову не придёт рисовать на мониторе картинки - и поэтому первые компьютеры были с текстовыми мониторами.  О том, что 640 Кбайт памяти будет достаточно каждому - и в 8086 была такая плохорасширяемая 16-битная схема адресации сегмент:смещение.  А ещё "Ни у кого не может возникнуть необходимость иметь компьютер в своем доме." :-)

Comment: Что-то у вас в голове каша, IMHO. Не думаю, что дальше в чём-то убеждать имеет смысл. Но уверен, вы просто не занимались программированием достаточно, чтобы понять о чём идёт речь.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff: тетрис на консоли зависит от TERMCAP, конечно.

Comment: @klopp - куда уж мне...  я даже не умею разбрасывать понты о том, что занимаюсь "реальными задачами, а не игрушечными упражнениями" ))  ведь именно это, с вашей точки зрения, отличает опытного программиста? ))))

Comment: Егорушка, можно подумать, кто-то у Вас отбирает Ваш любимый conio.h. Да он никому нафиг не нужен, пользуйтесь им на здоровье!

Comment: Соглашусь - conio не нужен. getch всегда можно написать самому из подручных средств, ну, и всегда можно воспользоваться curses/ncurses

Comment: @gecube Не всегда. curses/ncurses работают на терминалах. MS DOS терминала не предоставляет. (Там эмуляции терминалов есть, но это уже совсем другая история)

Comment: @alexlz: http://stackoverflow.com/q/138153/276994

Comment: @VladD MS DOS != MS Windows

Comment: Такой холивар, как будто каждый должен писать программы на си, которые могут работать на любом оборудовании от 4 разрядных процессоров и машин с байтами из 5 бит и до супер скалярных квантовых компьютеров будущего. Чаще всего в ТЗ пишут где должно работать, и если там есть conio.h, лучше он чем свой велосипед.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуем "догадаться":

```
 conIO => con I/O => Console Input/Output
```

Ну, а с функционалом, поставляемым этой библиотекой уже можно разобраться, почитав доки в сети.

Кроме того, "conio.h" - библиотека чисто сиШная, перешедшая в C++, и не ушедшая оттуда до сих пор чисто из-за того, что нужно поддерживать старый код.

Comment: @0xFFh Она не просто сишная. Она писюково-сишная.

Comment: @alexlz, не, она писюково-досовско-сишная

Comment: >и если там есть conio.h, лучше он чем свой велосипед.

@IronVbif, в том-то и дело, что даже если рассматривать только dos/pc, то свой велосипед будет намного лучше. Для решения многих практических задач (да почти всех) функционал conioi.h - от "неудобен" до "непригоден".